# Comparing and creating arrays without having to individually add elements to an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it so that if an array is equal to another array then do something.

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
gridArray.add(string1);
gridArray.add(string2);
gridArray.add(string3);
gridArray.add(string4);

if (array == {a,b,c,d}) {
....
}
if (array == {e,f,g,h}) {
....
}
```

string1 etc are all variables so will be different each time I run this bit of code. The main thing I want to achieve is to not have to add a,b,c,d etc individually to an array (like for 'array') because I am going to have a lot of the if statements with different values for a,b,c,d, and a lot more values than just a,b,c,d.

Answer (score 3):

This will be more verbose if you don't want to create arrays. The simple way would be:

```
if (array.equals(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d)) {}
```

This will return true if your arraylist [contains exactly a, b, c and d (in the same order)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

If you don't care about the order, you can also use `containsAll` but it will require an extra step:

```
List<String> target = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d);
if (array.containsAll(target) && array.size() == target.size()) {}
```

Comment: Makes me wonder which is more efficient; this, or `Arrays.equals(list.toArray(), otherArray)`.

Comment: It will most likely be extremely close. The constructor used by `Arrays.asList` does a simple assignment - so the only overhead is the object creation which should be minimal.

Comment: I suspect `Arrays.asList` will win, just because it only does constant allocation, not linear.

Answer (score 0):

[`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) have static [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) methods you can use for this:

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
if (Arrays.equals(array, new String[]{"a","b","c","d"})) {
    System.out.println("Equal!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [Apache Common's ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#isEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) compare feature:

```
 isEquals

public static boolean isEquals(java.lang.Object array1,
                               java.lang.Object array2)

    Compares two arrays, using equals(), handling multi-dimensional arrays correctly.
```